# Scrolling a LongListSelector by its Vertical Offset by getting its Viewport - can't add a dynamic value to SetViewportOrigin()

Tags: c#, scroll, viewport, longlistselector

So finally, I get the ViewportControl that I've been looking for the LongListSelector from so long but when I try to scroll to a specific offset using the below methods, I'm not able to scroll to the offset. 
I'm using a public static class `GlobalVars` (Global Variables) to pass data between pages.

So when a user selects an `item` from the LongListSelector -> Navigates to ItemDetail Page by this:

```
 private void llsArtists_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetFirstVisibleItem(llsArtists);
        var artist = (Artist)e.AddedItems[0];
        GlobalVars._artistName = artist.ArtistName;
        GetSelectedArtist(artist.ArtistName);

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ArtistDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and then comes back to the same page by hitting `Back` Key, I would like the user to be on the same item as the last one (currently it jumps to the first index.) Therefore, I get the Viewport and the vertical offset:

```
        private void GetFirstVisibleItem(LongListSelector lls)
    {     
        var offset = FindViewport(lls).Viewport.Top;
        GlobalVars._artistScrollOffset = offset;
    }


   private static ViewportControl FindViewport(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var elt = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (elt is ViewportControl)

                return (ViewportControl)elt;

            var result = FindViewport(elt);

            if (result != null) 
                return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and finally ScrollToOffset

```
        void ScrollToOffset()
    {
        Point loc = new Point();
        loc.X = 0;
        //loc.Y = Math.Round(GlobalVars._artistScrollOffset, 2);
        loc.Y = GlobalVars._artistScrollOffset;
        FindViewport(llsArtists).SetViewportOrigin(loc);
    }
```

The problem is - If I explicitly set the value of Y for the `Point` loc like I set the `loc.X = 0`, it just works fine! The LongListSelector works perfectly! But, if I would like it to be a variable which is exactly what I would like it to be - IT JUST DOESN'T WORK! I find this very strange? What could be causing this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over thinking this one quite a bit.  You shouldn't need to do anything, it should return to back to the page where it left off at the exact position.

The only thing I can think is that you're **"changing"/"resetting"** the `DataContext` or `ItemsSource` when you NavigateTo or NavigateFrom.  Other possibility is that you set the LongListSelector DataContent/ItemsSource on the `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` event.

If you did the last one, it will reset the list.

Either set the ItemsSource in the Constructor or change the `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` to something like this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myLongListSelector.ItemsSource == null)
    {
        // myLongListSelector.ItemsSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE;
    }        
}
```

This way it will only set it once so returning to the page doesn't reassign it.

Comment: Hi. I'm indeed clearing the ItemsSource and then retrieving the items again as otherwise when the user navigayes to the same page by going back. It adds duplicate values to the Collection. :S

Comment: @NavikGoswami Just retrieve the items once if the ItemsSource is null or do it in the Constructor of the page.  There is no need to clear if the items are the same.