# Change Image Pixel color to Redor any other in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone * development,in my project I need to convert the pixel of image to either Red,Green,Violet,etc colors as per my requirements.Can anyone send a sample code to do this process?

It would be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: I checked the following links,but didn't help me http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale

Comment: just to be clear, you are working on WP8 silverlight project or the winRT??

Comment: check [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/altering-pixels-windows-phone) one out. What didn't worked with the link you mentioned?? looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks,please also send more links if you get,In the link I sent there,I got error at using Bitmap,there was no class as Bitmap in WP8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my solution here for converting an image to gray scale.

[Convert A Dynamic Bitmap To Gray Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331358/convert-a-dynamic-bitmapimage-to-a-grayscale-bitmapimage-in-a-windows-phone-appl/26351477#26351477).

---

Play attention to the loop where I decode each Red,Green,Blue pixel out of the Pixel array and where I reassemble the picture back with `Buffer.BlockCopy`.  So basically you can do whatever you want with those components to modify your picture then BlockCopy it back.

---

```
private void PutPixel(int x, int y, byte red, byte green, byte blue, ref WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    if(wb == null)
        return;
    int[] PixelsBuffer = new int[1];
    unchecked
    {
        PixelsBuffer[0] = (int)( 0xFF000000 | (int)red << 16 | (int)green << 8 | blue);
    }
    int offset = ((y * wb.PixelWidth) + x) * 4;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(PixelsBuffer, 0, wb.Pixels, offset, 4);            
}
```

---

Code In Action

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" Stretch="None" />

// draw a white line from (0,0) to (100, 100)    
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)this.myImage.Source);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        PutPixel(i, i, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, ref wb);
    }
    myImage.Source = wb;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanx,but is this solution for converting the image to Red color or Red to Grey?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar It converts any image to the black and white.  I just use the AlignmentGrid image as an example (because it's included in all WP8.0 projects by default)

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar to convert the image to grayscale, look at the code.  I take the average of all 3 colors and set that as the color thus making it gray.

Comment: But can you suggest,what if I want to convert the image to Red or any different color?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Just think about it for a minute.  To convert to Red, just set the other color components to zero for each pixels.  What you will have left is just the Red Channel of the image.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Are you asking for a SetPixel(x,y,color) type thing?

Comment: Yes @Chubosaurus Software

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar You should be able to figure it out using the code I linked to.  It's basic algebra and some critical thinking skills.  See updated solution if you're having trouble.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar I added the expected resulted if you did everything correctly.