# Adjust image in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8.1

I want to adjust the contrast of an image in Windows Phone 8.1
 I have found samples for Windows Phone 7 but it does not work in Windows Phone 8.1.

This is my code:

```
    public static WriteableBitmap ChangeContrast(WriteableBitmap Bitmap,
                                                    int[] orgPixels,
                                                    double contrastValue)
    {
        var result = new WriteableBitmap(Bitmap.PixelWidth, Bitmap.PixelHeight);
        var contrastFactor = (50f + contrastValue) / 50f;
        contrastFactor *= contrastFactor;
        var contrastFactorIndex = (int)(contrastFactor * 32768);
        var inputPixels = Bitmap.PixelBuffer;
        int[] tempPixels = new int[Bitmap.PixelBuffer.Length];
        orgPixels.CopyTo(tempPixels, 0);
        if (0 != Bitmap.PixelBuffer.Length)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < Bitmap.PixelBuffer.Length; index++)
            {
                // Extract color components
                var color = tempPixels[index];
                var alpha = (byte)(color >> 24);
                var red = (byte)(color >> 16);
                var green = (byte)(color >> 8);
                var blue = (byte)(color);
                int ri = red - 128;
                int gi = green - 128;
                int bi = blue - 128;

                // Multiply contrast factor
                ri = (ri * contrastFactorIndex) >> 15;
                gi = (gi * contrastFactorIndex) >> 15;
                bi = (bi * contrastFactorIndex) >> 15;

                // Transform back to range [0, 255]
                ri = ri + 128;
                gi = gi + 128;
                bi = bi + 128;
                // Clamp to byte boundaries
                red = (byte)(ri > 255 ? 255 : (ri < 0 ? 0 : ri));
                green = (byte)(gi > 255 ? 255 : (gi < 0 ? 0 : gi));
                blue = (byte)(bi > 255 ? 255 : (bi < 0 ? 0 : bi));
                result.SetValue[index] = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
            }
        }
```

//additional         Buffer.BlockCopy(tempPixels, 0, inputPixels, 0, tempPixels.Length);

```
        return result;
    }
```

The 'SetValue' was 'pixels' in the original sample but Pixels does not exist in this object on WP8.1.

What is the equivalent please?

Comment: The following imaging sdk has the filtering that your are trying to use plus much much more http://developer.nokia.com/lumia/nokia-apis/imaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to modify the int[] tempPixels array.  Once you are finished with that you want to copy the tempPixel array back to the result.PixelBuffer.  You can use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy a block to another block.

Full example: how to adjust brightness: [Adjust Brightness WriteableBitmap 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672406/how-to-adjust-brightness-and-contrast-of-an-image-using-a-slider/26674170?noredirect=1#comment43202582_26674170)

Full example: grayscale an image: [Grayscale an Image WriteableBitmap 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331358/convert-a-dynamic-bitmapimage-to-a-grayscale-bitmapimage-in-a-windows-phone-appl/26351477#26351477)

---

Remember to add in `System.IO` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime` for the solutions above to work.

I also included the full 8.1 project here on my OneDrive: [Adjust Brightness Project 8.1](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!17211)

---

Comment: Hi, still getting errors like: 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'AsStream' 
cannot convert from 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer' to 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream' 
cannot convert from 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer' to 'System.Array'

Comment: I believe this is because I am create a Windows Phone  Store App

Comment: @AndrewSimpson are you running 8.1 Silverlight or 8.1 runtime?

Comment: 8.1 runtime. I am new to wp development. Had not realised there were 2 types

Comment: @AndrewSimpson `using (Stream input = writeable_bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())` should work in 8.1 runtime.  Did you forget to include System.IO?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting.  Yes, I have included that namespace :).  The error is telling me that Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer does not contain a definition for  AsStream

Comment: @AndrewSimpson must being missing some includes.  `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;` perhaps?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson checked out the onedrive project: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F2F16D176D29EFC!17211 (it should almost convert to phone 8.1 runtime 1:1)

Comment: thanks for all that. Just ported it all over and it works. I was missing the using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; namespace - lol

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Wweet, glad it worked out for you.  I updated the solution to added in the new info.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware How to change each image pixel color of downloaded png image and store it in isolated storage after color has been changed?